# ARMv8 AArch64 SVC saving registers

Tags: arm

Say I have a simple aarch64 function that makes a system call via SVC, looks something like this (iOS target):

```
make_syscall:
    stp fp, lr, [sp, #-16]!
    add fp, sp, #0             
    mov x16, SYSCALL_NUM       
    svc #128                   
    ldp fp, lr, [sp], #16      
    ret
```

Question: since the function only modifies x16, which is caller-saved, is there any need to save/restore any other registers besides the frame pointer and link register? In other words, can one assume SVC handlers respect the ABI procedure calling conventions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find where the question is answered:
https://events.linuxfoundation.org/images/stories/pdf/lcna_co2012_marinas.pdf
On page 14-15, it talks about what arm 64bit does when user mode is transferred to higher mode.
Simply to say, the kernel saves the GPRs onto the kernel stack automatically, but not explicitly as user codes do.